# How to write X.Base.Descendant where X.Base both a class and module

Tags: typescript

Here is the ambient declaration code (I'm using TypeScript 0.9.1.1):

```
// file Base.d.ts
declare module X
{
    export class Base
    {
    }
}

// file Descendant.d.ts
declare module X.Base
{
    export class Descendant extends Base
    {

    }
}
```

Compiler says:

> Type reference cannot refer to container 'X.Base'

I have only found a workaround by putting everything into a single module in a single file:

```
declare module X {
    export class Base {
    }

    export module Base {
        export class Descendant extends X.Base {

        }
    }
}
```

**BUT** I want to keep both classes in separate files. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it gets shadowed:

```
// file Base.d.ts
declare module X
{
    export class Base
    {
    }
}

// file Descendant.d.ts
declare module X.Base
{
    // Starting at this point Base will always refer to 
    // module not the class
}
```

PS: for your single file solution you got lucky. Since order seems to matter (which shouldn't be the case). i.e. the following is an Error (module declared before class):

```
declare module X {
    export module Base {
    }

    export class Base {
    }
}
```

Filed a bug report : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1701

Comment: As for the bug you filed, I probably recall some discussion at codeplex.

Comment: So, the bug is closed. It seems there is no way and probably will never be to do definitions in question in separate files because of the order in which files are processed and shadow one another?